# SSL expired web root certificate for one client, on some computers but not others

Tags: networking, ssl, ssl-certificate

I'm a non-network pro who has a situation with one of our largest clients. They get the red Certificate Invalid icon, because of an outdated, expired root certificate. However, our certificate is up to date, and none of our other clients have this problem.

[image]

In fact, it happens only on about *half of their computers* and not others, despite having the same network, the same computers, and using the same browser. This is on mac/Chrome, and clearing their cache - which I've read will clear certificates as well - also doesn't do anything.

This company is known to have really strict security.

Any thoughts about why similar computers on this same network might not be renewing certificates?

Thanks.

Comment: Are the all computers updated?

Comment: What CA is the _intermediate_ certificate from? (That is, the one between server cert and root cert.) There is a certain [widely known certificate authority](https://letsencrypt.org/docs/dst-root-ca-x3-expiration-september-2021/) whose intermediates are cross-signed by two different root CAs, and depending on the system (some devices may have the new root installed and others not; some OS are better at building alternate validation paths than others) the different results can happen.

Comment: Is this question entirely about macOS? If so, which version of macOS?

Comment: It sounds like those that failed are running an old o/s version.

Comment: @DanielB seems to be happening w/ Yosemite.

Comment: Did turn out to be the old/s version. Thanks all especially user1686 for pointing it out. Feel free to create an answer here for me to mark it as correct.